# Is it possible to implement a ReadWriteLock by using volatile variables only? By using Atomics and volatile?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

In java, is it possible to implement a ReadWriteLock by using volatile variables only?

Otherwise, how one would implement it by using Atomics and volatile variables?

I had an interview question how to implement ReadWriteLock without using locks.

When I tried to explore using Atomics, interviewer steered away from using atomics and suggested that it is possible to implement it using only volatile variables.

I can't come up with a way how to implement it with volatiles only.

Comment: It seems, you already know the answer to the first (“is it possible”) question, as otherwise, you wouldn’t ask the second (“how” to do a different approach) question at the same time. Recommend read: [ask]

Comment: I had an interview question about this. When I tried to explore using Atomics, interviewer steered away from using atomics and suggested that it is possible to implement it using only volatile variables. I can't come up with a way how to implement it with volatiles only, hence posted this to get a firm confirmation or suggestion. Thank you

Comment: A Lock is a tool for a specific problem, blocking other threads from entering the same part of your code. The Atomic classes and behaviour of `volatile` serves an entirely different purpose.

Comment: From what I can deduce from interview questions posted on Stackoverflow, it seems it isn’t worth thinking about interview questions at all. Most of them seem to exist only because the interviewer wanted to show off with their half-knowledge, rather than finding a good programmer.

Comment: If we talk about a lock complying to the [`ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) interface, it must support waiting queues and even if you manage to implement it with volatile variables only, which implies using polling loops, no one would use such a thing in practice. So what would be the purpose of showing that you can implement an unusable replacement to a built-in feature? That’s nothing I would hire a programmer for…

Comment: thank you for analysing my interviewer's motives :) - that might be the case.
Yet I can imagine in a low latency environment having a busy spin rather than a lock could work faster. Still I'm interested if using volatiles only and loops would do the job as my concern is that incrementing a volatile will not happen atomically, so would require atomics. Im still curious about this?

Comment: Right, you can not use increments, as increments are not atomic. You have to work with only reads and writes, e.g. of zero and one resp. false and true. See [Dekker's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm) (and the “See also” section at the bottom of the page), for example(s). Keep in mind that an algorithm for mutual exclusive access without reentrance support is still enough, as you can implement a read/write lock with reentrance atop it, by using the former to protect the internal data structure of the latter.

Comment: this algorithm is a good answer - thank you.

Comment: Turn it around.  Ask the interviewer:  "You hire someone to build your house.  Instead of laying a foundation and starting building your house, he starts to build a steel mill and a finishing plant to turn raw iron ore into nails and screws.  You're paying him by the hour to do this, and he's not building your house. What do you do?"

Comment: While you are right and that could be an indication of the hiring manager attitude, I learned never to push back hard against the interviewer if I want a job. 

Also, my question here yielded some good references to areas that I didn't know. Which was my goal - to learn more about the question I asked.

Answer (score 1):

[Peterson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm) is one of the simplest algorithms for mutual exclusion that uses only volatile variables. I suppose it can be transformed to `ReadWriteLock`.

Also I can recommend [The Art of Multiprocessor Programming by Herlihy and Shavit](https://dl.acm.org/doi/book/10.5555/2385452): specifically chapters 2 (it has nice explanations for the Peterson Lock), 7 (about spin-locks), 8 (about readers–writers lock), and 5 (about the consensus number, which explains principal difference between `volatile` and `Atomic*`).

Comment: thank you for the references! The book is a great finding as I never came across it or didn't pay attention.